# How to count the number of 1's a number will have in binary?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best algorithm to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

How do I count the number of `1`'s a number will have in binary?

So let's say I have the number `45`, which is equal to `101101` in binary and has 4 `1`'s in it. What's the most efficient way to write an algorithm to do this?

Comment: How is the number given to you [represented]? Or is it theoretical?

Comment: See http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: Is this homework? And what have you tried?

Comment: FYI, this operation is commonly called "popcount".

Comment: +1 for a question which has turned up some really informative answers

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Instead of writing an algorithm to do this its best to use the built in function. [Integer.bitCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount%28int%29)

What makes this especially efficient is that the JVM can treat this as an intrinsic. i.e. recognise and replace the whole thing with a single machine code instruction on a platform which supports it e.g. Intel/AMD

---

To demonstrate how effective this optimisation is

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    perfTestIntrinsic();

    perfTestACopy();
}

private static void perfTestIntrinsic() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    long countBits = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
        countBits += Integer.bitCount(i);
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Intrinsic: Each bit count took %.1f ns, countBits=%d%n", (double) time / Integer.MAX_VALUE, countBits);
}

private static void perfTestACopy() {
    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    long countBits2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
        countBits2 += myBitCount(i);
    long time2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;
    System.out.printf("Copy of same code: Each bit count took %.1f ns, countBits=%d%n", (double) time2 / Integer.MAX_VALUE, countBits2);
}

// Copied from Integer.bitCount()
public static int myBitCount(int i) {
    // HD, Figure 5-2
    i = i - ((i >>> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >>> 2) & 0x33333333);
    i = (i + (i >>> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f;
    i = i + (i >>> 8);
    i = i + (i >>> 16);
    return i & 0x3f;
}
```

prints

```
Intrinsic: Each bit count took 0.4 ns, countBits=33285996513
Copy of same code: Each bit count took 2.4 ns, countBits=33285996513
```

Each bit count using the intrinsic version and loop takes just 0.4 nano-second on average. Using a **copy of the same code** takes 6x longer (gets the same result)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: can you please describe your test environment? On my machine (Xeon W3520@2.67GHz, 32-bit Java 7 running on Win7 x64) I got: "Intrinsic: Each bit count took 8.1 ns, Copy of same code: Each bit count took 8.1 ns", and when I manually inline `myBitCount()` I got 8.1ns vs. 5.4ns, respectively.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I'm not particularly interested in absolute numbers, I'd really like to know whether `Integer.bitCount(i)` makes use of `POPCNT` or similar processor instruction or not. Looking at my results I started to doubt it does.

Comment: If you have an old version of Java, I wouldn't be surprised if it isn't as optimal.  Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I used Java SE 7u3 to run your benchmark.

Comment: Interesting, so did I.  I have an Intel i7 with a 64-bit JVM. I am amazed it was 20x slower. :P  Can you check you are using the `-server` JVM?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: tomorrow morning I will run it on 64-bit server JVM (I used 32-bit) and tell you the results. 20x speed difference is indeed amazing.

Comment: On `-server` x64 Java 7u3 I've got 0.9ns vs 4.2ns (`Integer.bitCout()` vs bit shifting shenanigans), i.e. the same proportion you had on your machine.

Comment: The server JVM can optimise the code more aggressively, but has a longer start up time. The 32-bit windows JVM is `-client` by default, but just about every other OS its `-server`. I believe the 64-bit JVM on Windows is also `-server` by default.

Answer (score 36):

The most efficient way to count the number of 1's in a 32-bit variable `v` I know of is:

```
v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);
v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);
c = ((v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24; // c is the result
```

**Updated:** I want to make clear that it's not my code, actually it's older than me. According to [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) ([The Art of Computer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) Vol IV, p 11), the code first appeared in the first textbook on programming, [The Preparation of Programs for an Electronic Digital Computer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262231182) by Wilkes, Wheeler and Gill (2nd Ed 1957, reprinted 1984). Pages 191–193 of the 2nd edition of the book presented *Nifty Parallel Count* by D B Gillies and J C P Miller.

Comment: +1 For the complete reference.

Comment: Peter Lawrey said he copied his code from Integer.bitCount(), and this is shorter. Why didn't the Java people use this implementation?

Comment: How about an explanation for this monstrocity?

Answer (score 15):

See [Bit Twidling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive) and study all the 'counting bits set' algorithms.  In particular, Brian Kernighan's way is simple and quite fast if you expect a small answer.  If you expect an evenly distributed answer, lookup table might be better.

Answer (score 5):

This is called [Hamming weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight). It is also called the `population count`, `popcount` or `sideways sum`.

Answer (score 2):

The following is either from "Bit Twiddling Hacks" page or [Knuth's books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) (I don't remember). It is adapted to unsigned 64 bit integers and works on C#. I don't know if the lack of unsigned values in Java creates a problem.

By the way, I write the code only for reference; the best answer is using `Integer.bitCount()` as @Lawrey said; since there is a specific machine code operation for this operation in some (but not all) CPUs.

```
  const UInt64 m1 = 0x5555555555555555;
  const UInt64 m2 = 0x3333333333333333;
  const UInt64 m4 = 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f;
  const UInt64 h01 = 0x0101010101010101;

  public int Count(UInt64 x)
  {
      x -= (x >> 1) & m1;
      x = (x & m2) + ((x >> 2) & m2);
      x = (x + (x >> 4)) & m4;
      return (int) ((x * h01) >> 56);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int f(int n) 
{
    int result = 0;
    for(;n > 0; n = n >> 1)
        result += ((n & 1) == 1 ? 1 : 0);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is not an efficient algorithm, see other answers.

Comment: `((n & 1) == 1 ? 1 : 0)` is the same as `n & 1`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you're right, it is. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest I have used and also seen in a practical implementation (in the open source [Sphinx Search Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_%28search_engine%29)) is the [MIT HAKMEM algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAKMEM). It runs superfast over a very large stream of 1's and 0's.

Answer (score 0):

The following Ruby code works for positive numbers.

```
count = 0
while num > 1
    count = (num % 2 == 1) ? count + 1 : count
    num = num >> 1
end
count += 1
return count
```

Comment: This is not an efficient algorithm, see other answers.